# Find the length of a rectifiable curve $a(t)=(t,t^2)$ on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $a(t)=(t,t^2)$ be defined on $[0,1]$.
Put $s_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{(2i-1)^2}{n^2}} $.

I want to show the exsitence of the limit of $\{s_n\}$ and find its limit without the Riemann integration.

To show the existence, I tried to show that the sequence is increasing and bounded. But, it is hard to prove that $\{s_n\}$ is increasing. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{array}{l}
\alpha (t) = (t,{t^2})\\
\frac{d}{{dt}}\alpha (t) = (1,2t)
\end{array}

Length of $\frac{d}{{dt}}\alpha (t)$
$$\left\| {\frac{d}{{dt}}\alpha (t)} \right\| = \sqrt {4{t^2}+1}$$
Arclenght for [0,1]

$$\int_0^1 {\left\| {\frac{d}{{dt}}\alpha (t)} \right\|} dt = \frac{1}{4}(\sqrt 5  + \sinh ^{-1}{(2)})$$

Arclenght for $[0,t]$

$$\int_0^t \sqrt{4 \tau ^2+1} \, d\tau =\frac{1}{2}  t\sqrt{4 t^2+1}+\frac{1}{4} \sinh ^{-1}(2 t)$$

Comment: Did this, to see in what kind of limit we are confronted with.

Comment: How is this helpful to find the limit "without using Riemann integration"?

Comment: I have had no idea, how the limit looks like. If I have a first
look on the limit as value, I'm hoping to get an idea to work on.

Comment: If the limit exists, then I think we can easily find its limit value. So, the existence is surely required. I have tried to show the sequence is increasing and bounded. To show its boundedness is easier than to check it is increasing. Thus, I want to see that the sequence is increasing.

Comment: @JeongHobin:

Everything is ok. I worked with:
$$\begin{array}{l}
a(k,n) = \frac{1}{n}\sqrt {1 + {{\left( {\frac{{1 + 2 \cdot k}}{n}} \right)}^2}} \\
s(n) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {a(k,n)} 
\end{array}$$

For n=1000 I've got

$$\begin{array}{l}
\int_0^1 {\sqrt {(1,2t).(1,2t)} } {\kern 1pt} dt = 1.4789428575445975\\
{\rm{s(1000)}} = {\rm{1}}{\rm{.4789427830089972}}
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Frieder The approximation is ok but I want to prove the sequence is increasing without the Riemann integration.

Comment: @JeongHobin: I know, but at the moment I've no idea. Thought yesterday, didn't see any point to start with. I'm very sorry.